# Unity platform pathfinding

Tags: unity-game-engine, path-finding, a-star

I've been trying to find a way to do this but I'm not sure how. I've gone through A* pathfinding but could find anything on this. What I'm looking for is pathfinding for something kind of like a super smash bros level with different platforms. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This may be better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to move it or should I repost it there?

Comment: Just delete this question and ask it again over there. Do note however that your question is not off-topic here.

Comment: Its not off-topic, but he may get better/quicker responses on the other site. Hoping someone can help him as it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the path as being made of game states instead of locations; you are looking for a gamestate in which your character is alive and on the platform. The branches of your search would be button presses.

Imagine it this way; the computer pretends it clicked a button and estimates how the game would be *x* milliseconds after that. Then the computer looks at the buttons it may click and chooses the best alternate reality. It then clicks that button. Lo and behold, the game turns out exactly like the computer imagined.

You will need to limit the rate at which the computer may imagine pressing new buttons (if you don't want to lose performance). In order to do this, you may limit it to only pressing a button every 10 ms in its imagination. That may lead it to stand still when it had the option to move. You may also limit the button presses by game state; it can't click 'jump' if it already has jumped.

In essence, use an A* prediction algorithm instead of an A* pathfinding algorithm. Also consider minimax, which is already a prediction algorithm.